# Phrasing "I just came from the museum by foot": "Je viens du musée à pied"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, formulation-idiomatique, compléments

I want to say "I just came from the museum by foot" is "Je viens du musée à pied" correct? I know that "je viens de" translates to "I just came from" but I am unsure if it changes when you have a location and you're explaining how you came "by foot"

Answer (score 5):

"***Je viens de***" translates "**I come from**" so "**I just came from**" would be better translated by "***j'arrive juste de***", "***je viens juste d'arriver/de revenir de***", or "***je reviens juste de***" and similar expressions.

They are valid whatever the method used (by feet, car or whatever).

So, here is a possible idiomatic translation (which assumes you came back from the museum to your current location):

> *Je viens juste de revenir du musée à pied.*

Comment: Doesn't "je viens de revenir" already mean that I have *just* come back? Is the "juste" optional?

Comment: They overlap but differ in their validity time span. *Je viens de revenir* can be said for a longer time than *je viens juste de revenir*, and on the opposite for a shorter time than *je suis revenu*. I used *juste* because like the English *just* (or at least that's the way I perceive it, *juste* suggests than only a very short period of time has elapsed.